# how to call objects created in a loop?

Tags: actionscript-3, object, for-loop

Newbie question:

If I create several shape objects in a loop, like:

```
var i:int; 
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    var circle:Shape = new Shape();
    circle.graphics.beginFill(color);
    circle.graphics.drawCircle(100,100, radius);
    circle.graphics.endFill();
    addChild(circle);   
}
```

How can I then call those different shapes *separately*, so I could manipulate their properties? It would seem to me they would all have the same name?

Comment: Maybe keep an array instead of a single variable.

Comment: Best practice would be to put your objects into an `Array` or `Vector` (as suggested in an answer), and do not create a new var on every loop iteration.

Answer (score 1):

You can access them via their index (the order they have been put on the stage).
So something like:

```
DisplayObject(getChildAt(1)).x = 100; // Where the 1 is the index (starting at 0)
```

Comment: That's possible, but it is bad practice.

Comment: No it might not be but it is a good solution. Do you have a good solution?

Comment: Yes, but it's already been posted in the other answer. Use an `Array` or a `Vector`.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you can just have an array (or vector) of objects, so you won't depend on current displaylist.

```
var i:int; 
var circleArray:Array = new Array();
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    var circle:Shape = new Shape();
    circleArrayList.push(circle);
    circle.graphics.beginFill(color);
    circle.graphics.drawCircle(100,100, radius);
    circle.graphics.endFill();
    addChild(circle);   
}
//And then access them with
for(i = 0; i < circleArray.length, i++)
{
    circleArrayList[i].x = 15 * i;
}
//Or
foreach(var circle:DisplayObject in circleArray)
{
    circle.x = 15 * i;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, you definitely do not want to use `ArrayList`. At the very worst, use `Array` as ArrayList is a Flex component and it adds a bunch of overhead because it is nothing more than a wrapper for an Array. It's the same as people consistently using `MovieClip` over `Sprite`. That said, in this case you don't want to use an Array at all, but a `Vector`

Comment: OMG misspelled. pure AS3 doesn't have an ArrayList at all :)
It's just logical approach, the author of the question didn't ask for the most quick way to do it. Moreover, Vectors are not supported in flash player versions prior to 10 (which is not crucial, but who knows - some developers still create games for 9'th version of the player - it's almost a standard for them)
But Vectors are quicker, yes.

Answer (score -1):

```
for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
{
class x =new class(i);
x.print()
}
```